# publish only one folder on gitHub on a parallel branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab, github-pages

I need to do that in my git master branch, only the contents of a folder called dist are published in a parallel branch that I am calling SRC, I am working with Angular 5 and basically what I want is that my project (source) is in a page and my ghPage (result) in another branch without the source code, first of all thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branches in Git are kind of labels, so if you create a new branch from master,it will be a label to exactly same state where master is right now.

So what you can do is

- create a new branch from master and checkout the same.

  git checkout -b SRC
- Now, delete every other folder than dist
- Add your changes to staging area using git add command or you can also use git GUI for this.
- commit your changes into SRC branch and push the same.

Now *SRC* branch will be having only contents of your dist folder whereas state of *master* is unaffected.

Comment: Instead of starting the branch at the commit where `master` currently is, add the `--orphan` option to `git checkout` to create a new branch that does not unnecessarily share its history with `master`.